# Paging 3 library using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-paging-3

I am working on Paging 3 library and facing a issue which is like in my PagingSource class my load(params: LoadParams) returns the value before I get the response from API.
I have added callback for the API response but still I am facing the same problem.

Any hack on how to solve this?

```
class FeedDatasource(var application: FeedActivity) :
    PagingSource<Int, FeedModel.Success_data>(), APICallback {

 override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, FeedModel.Success_data> {
        return try {
            // Start refresh at page 1 if undefined.
            nextPage = params.key ?: 1
            getFeedsData(params)
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = feedModel.success_data!!,
                prevKey = if (nextPage == 1) null else nextPage - 1,
                nextKey = nextPage + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
      }
    }

    // APICallback override method
    override fun success(response: MutableLiveData<JsonElement>) {
        response.observe(application, { jsonElement ->
            feedModel = Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, FeedModel::class.java)
        })
    }



fun getFeedsData(params: LoadParams<Int>) {
        val nextPage = params.key ?: 1
        if (nextPage <= feedModel.total_page!!) {
            UserRepository.callAPI(
                getJsonObject(nextPage),
                AppConstants.APIMarks.FEED_LIST,
                AppConstants.HTTPMethod.HTTP_POST, this
            )
        }
    }




interface APICallback {

    fun success(response: MutableLiveData<JsonElement>)

    fun failure()

}
```

Comment: You can't use callbacks here. You need to turn that callback based code into a suspend function and then call it from the `load` function. You can use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to convert your callback code to a suspend function.

Comment: I don't have idea about that. Can you please help me out on how to do this Arpit?

Comment: I can try. Add the revelant functions in questions, like `getFeedsData`. What is `feedModel.success_data` and `APICallback`?

Comment: I have added all the things you asked for

Comment: Add code for `UserRepository.callAPI` function as well.

Comment: It is my API call method. I have used retrfit with rxjava2 observable

Comment: You are passing `this` to the `callAPI` function which I guess refers to `APICallback`. You need to make `callAPI` a suspend function. I don't have experience with rxjava so won't be able to help there but Retrofit supports suspend functions so you can mark you retrofit functions as suspend and then call them from `UserRepository.callAPI`